# reload Terminal preferences .plist after change

Tags: terminal, applescript, osascript

I used plutil to edit the plist. then I placed in under `/User/<myUsername>/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist`. I want it to update the settings without reboot the application. How do I do this? using `defaults read com.apple.Terminal` doesn't seem to make the changes take effect. I added a terminal profile to the plist and want the changes to take effect.

I tried making an import profile with AppleScript but long story short it's not 100% possible. if you store window 1 so it's the same var in-between delays right after open it errors more times.

```
on run argv
    set importScript to first item of argv
    set flag to application "Terminal" is not running
    tell application "Terminal"
        open importScript
        delay 1.0E-5
        activate
        if flag then close back window
        do script "exit" in window 1
        delay 0.5
        close window 1
    end tell
end run
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no need for editing plists just a simple AppleScript. the limitations of this are you must have `_oti_<yourProfileId>` in your terminal profile default header and change the title when running your terminal profile to prevent accidental closures when installing the same profile of an already running app

import.applescript

```
on run argv
    set importScript to first item of argv
    set closeScript to second item of argv
    set profileId to third item of argv
    do shell script "open -a Terminal " & importScript
    do shell script "osascript " & closeScript & " _oti_" & profileId
end run
```

closeMe.applescript

```
on run argv
    set c to first item in argv
    tell application "Terminal"
        set wList to every window
        repeat with app_window in wList
            set wname to name of app_window
            if wname contains c then
                do script "exit" in app_window
                delay 0.312
                close app_window
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
end run
```

and then you can call the profile using this AppleScript

```
on run argv
    set flag to application "Terminal" is not running
    set scpt to first item in argv
    set n to second item in argv
    set p to third item in argv
    tell application "Terminal"
        set newTab to do script scpt
        set badFlag to back window is equal to window 1
        if p is not equal to "" then set current settings of newTab to settings set p
        set custom title of newTab to n
        activate
        if flag and (not badFlag) then
            do script "exit" in back window
            delay 0.1
            close back window
        end if
    end tell
end run
```